# How to display data in WPF datagrid in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

My xaml code

```
<Window x:Class="SampleWPFApp.View.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:SampleWPFApp.ViewModel"
        Title="Window1" Height="500" Width="500">
    <Window.Resources>
        <viewmodel:FirstPageViewModel x:Key="fp"></viewmodel:FirstPageViewModel>
    </Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="75,38,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding FirstName, Source={StaticResource fp}}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="75,79,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding LastName, Source={StaticResource fp}}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <Button Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="104,118,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="0.093,1.636" Command="{Binding acomm, Source={StaticResource fp}}" />
    <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="mydatagrid" Margin="47,194,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="178" Width="385" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyDataGrid,Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" DataContext="{DynamicResource fp} " Loaded="DataGrid_Loaded"/>
</Grid>
```

My property where grid is bound to in ViewModel,

```
private List<Employee> mysampleGrid;
public List<Employee> MySampleGrid
{
    get
    {
        return mysampleGrid;
    }
    set
    {
        mysampleGrid = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MySampleGrid");
    }
}
```

Method called when button is clicked in ViewModel,

```
public void AddDataToDb()
{            

    e.FirstName = FirstName;
    e.LastName = LastName;
    context.Employees.Add(e);
    context.SaveChanges();
    this.MySampleGrid = null;

    //Setting List to value from database after inserting into db
    MySampleGrid = context.Employees.Where(x => x.FirstName != null).ToList();

}
```

But even after setting value of list(which is bound to datagrid) from database grid is not getting updated/refreshed in UI.please help. i have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**you can do a couple of things to improve your code.**

1. First i will suggest you use ObservableCollection since it has
   Change tracking mechanism.
2. Also set the DataContext of your grid to your viewmodel instead of
   individual control's datacontext to your viewmodel

putting everything together your code show now look like this:

```
     private ObservableCollection<Employee> mysampleGrid=new ObservableCollection<Employee>();

            public ObservableCollection<Employee> MysampleGrid
            {
                get { return mysampleGrid; }
                set { mysampleGrid= value; }            
            }

public void AddDataToDb()
    {            

        e.FirstName = FirstName;
        e.LastName = LastName;
        context.Employees.Add(e);
        context.SaveChanges();
        this.MySampleGrid = null;

        //Setting List to value from database after inserting into db
        var employees = context.Employees.Where(x => x.FirstName != null).ToList();
        foreach(var employee in employees)
        mysampleGrid.Add(employee);
    }
```

then finally in your view

```
<Window x:Class="SampleWPFApp.View.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:SampleWPFApp.ViewModel"
        Title="Window1" Height="500" Width="500">
    <Window.Resources>
        <viewmodel:FirstPageViewModel x:Key="fp"></viewmodel:FirstPageViewModel>
    </Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource fp}">
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="75,38,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding FirstName}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="75,79,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding LastName}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
            <Button Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="104,118,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="0.093,1.636" Command="{Binding acomm}" />
            <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="mydatagrid" Margin="47,194,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="178" Width="385" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MysampleGrid,Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"  Loaded="DataGrid_Loaded"/>

        </Grid>
```

Comment: @Pamparanapa , Observable collection example was good . but if i want to query data from multiple entities , simply changing List<Employee> to IEnumerable<object> would work , but ObservalbeCollection<object> wont work in this scenario.right?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at your `ItemsSource` binding:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyDataGrid,Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
```

You'll notice that the property you're binding to doesn't exist.  This should be `MySampleGrid`.

As an aside, most of the contents of the binding can be omitted, this should be all that is required:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding MySampleGrid}"
```

It would also make sense to set the `DataContext` of your `Window`, the child elements will inherit from this and the remaining `DataContext` attributes can be removed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out !.That was a silly mistake .Also if i remove DataContext attribute , data doesnt seem to appear.

Comment: @sujai remove it *and set the DataContext of your Window*. Just removing them will break it.